# Javascript drop down menu and validate calendar picker

Tags: javascript, java, date, drop-down-menu

Ok I have a drop down menu that is dynamically generated by .jsp and populated with data fetched from database.[2 dropdown list and 2 datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXhhU.png)
The problem that I am having is with a JS validation, am not so good with JavaScript but for the purposes of my mini project I have to work with it anyway....

The problem is that with JS I am checking if a user has selected two drop-down fields and two date pickers so the form can be submitted and the list of the searching should be shows below the button else display a warning message indicating that the drop-downs and date pickers have not been filled.

Where should I do the validation of those 4 fields? How to use the'EXECUTE' to call the class from 'SelectOperation.java'(as per attached).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;

import entityBeans.AccessLevel;
import entityBeans.Business;
import entityBeans.CustomerBranch;
import entityBeans.Menu;
import entityBeans.TransactionLog;
import entityBeans.User;
import cmnUtilities.CmnConstants;

public class SelectOperation { 
    Session session =  ConnectionMySQL.getInstance().getConnection();
    private static SelectOperation selectData = new SelectOperation();

    private SelectOperation()
    {
    }
    public User Select_login_User(String user_id)
    {

        User loginUser = null;
         try
         {
          loginUser = (User)session.get(User.class,user_id.trim());
         }
         catch(Exception exception)
         {
             exception.printStackTrace();   
         }
        return loginUser; 
    }
    public User Chech_User_existence(String user_id)
    {

        User CheckUser = null;
         try
         {
             CheckUser = (User)session.get(User.class,user_id.trim());
         }
         catch(Exception exception)
         {
             exception.printStackTrace();   
         }
        return CheckUser; 
    }
    public List<List<Menu>> Select_User_Menu(int Access_id)
    {

        List<Menu> UserMenu = null;
       List<List<Menu>>  Menus = new ArrayList<List<Menu>>();
        AccessLevel acl = null ;
         try
         {
             if(session.isOpen())
             {
            // acl =     (AccessLevel)session.get(AccessLevel.class,Access_id.trim());
            // StringBuffer AccessLevel = formatedMenuIds(acl.getMenuId());
            // System.out.println(AccessLevel);

             //UserMenu = (List<Menu>)session.createQuery("from Menu where menuId in ("+menuIds+")").list();
             UserMenu = (List<Menu>)session.createQuery("from Menu where menuAccLevel >='"+Access_id+"'").list();

             List<Menu> MainModule = new ArrayList<Menu>();
             List<Menu> SubModule = new ArrayList<Menu>();

             for(Menu seperateMenu : UserMenu)
             {
                 if((seperateMenu.getMenuId().length()) == CmnConstants.MAIN_MENU)
                 {
                     MainModule.add(seperateMenu); 
                 }
                 if((seperateMenu.getMenuId().length()) == CmnConstants.SUB_MENU)
                 {
                     SubModule.add(seperateMenu); 
                 }
             }

             for(Menu disp1 : MainModule)
             {
             List<Menu>  finaly = new ArrayList<Menu>();
             finaly.add(disp1);
             for(Menu disp2 : SubModule)
             {
             if(disp2.getMenuId().startsWith(disp1.getMenuId()))
             {
                 finaly.add(disp2);
             }
             }
             Menus.add(finaly);
             }
            System.out.println(Menus);
             }
             else
             {
                 System.out.println("session closed"); 
             }
         }
         catch(Exception exception)
         {
             exception.printStackTrace();   
         }
        return Menus; 
    }
    //METHOD RETURNS ALL ACCESS LEVEL CODE AND IT'S DESCRIPTION
    public List<AccessLevel> getAllAccessLevel()
    {
        List<AccessLevel> accessList = null;
        try
        {
        accessList = (List<AccessLevel>)session.createQuery("from AccessLevel").list();
        System.out.println(accessList);
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();    
        }
        return accessList;
    }
    //METHOD TO SELECT ALL BRANCH IDS
    public  List<CustomerBranch> getAllCustomerBranch()
    {
        List<CustomerBranch> branchList = null;
        try
        {
        branchList = (List<CustomerBranch>)session.createQuery("from CustomerBranch").list();
        System.out.println(branchList);
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();    
        }
        return branchList;
    }
    //METHOD TO SELECT ALL TRANSACTION_LOG DETAILS
    public  List<TransactionLog> getAllTransactionLog()
       {
        List<TransactionLog> TxnList = null;
            try
            {
                TxnList = (List<TransactionLog>)session.createQuery("from TransactionLog").list();
            System.out.println(TxnList);
            }
            catch(Exception exception)
            {
                exception.printStackTrace();    
            }
            return TxnList;
        }

    //METHOD TO SELECT ALL BUSINESS
        public  List<Business> getAllBusiness()
           {
            List<Business> BusinessList = null;
                try
                {
                    BusinessList = (List<Business>)session.createQuery("from Business").list();
                System.out.println(BusinessList);
                }
                catch(Exception exception)
                {
                    exception.printStackTrace();    
                }
                return BusinessList;
            }

        public Business SelectBusiness_Id(String business_id)
        {

            Business CheckBusiness_id = null;
             try
             {
                 CheckBusiness_id = (Business)session.get(Business.class,business_id.trim());
             }
             catch(Exception exception)
             {
                 exception.printStackTrace();   
             }
            return CheckBusiness_id; 
        }

        public CustomerBranch SelectBranch_Id(String branch_id)
        {
            CustomerBranch CheckBranch_id = null;
                 try
                 {
                     CheckBranch_id = (CustomerBranch)session.get(CustomerBranch.class,branch_id.trim());
                 }
                 catch(Exception exception)
                 {
                     exception.printStackTrace();   
                 }
                return CheckBranch_id; 
            }



        public TransactionLog FromDateSel(String txn_date)
        {

            TransactionLog transDateFrom = null;
             try
             {
                 transDateFrom = (TransactionLog)session.get(TransactionLog.class,txn_date.trim());
             }
             catch(Exception exception)
             {
                 exception.printStackTrace();   
             }
            return transDateFrom; 
        }
        public TransactionLog ToDateSel(String txn_date)
        {

            TransactionLog transDateTo = null;
             try
             {
                 transDateTo = (TransactionLog)session.get(TransactionLog.class,txn_date.trim());
             }
             catch(Exception exception)
             {
                 exception.printStackTrace();   
             }

            return transDateTo; 
        }


    // Will returns all menu ids
    /*public StringBuffer formatedMenuIds(String text)
    {
         String[] val = text.split(",");
         StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
         for(String cc :val)
         {
             sb.append("'"+cc+"'"+",");
         }
         if(sb.toString().endsWith(","))
         {
             sb.delete(sb.length()-1, sb.length());  
         }  
         return sb;
    }*/

    public static SelectOperation getInstance()
    {
        return selectData;
    }


}
```

I think i just need so more javascript to do this i just dont know how. Thanks for your help in advance.

```js
<% @page import = "allDatabaseOperations.SelectOperation" %>
  <% @page import = "java.util.List" %>
  <% @page import = "entityBeans.TransactionLog" %>
  <% @page import = "entityBeans.Business" %> 
  <% @page import = "entityBeans.CustomerBranch" %> 
  <% @page language = "java"
contentType = "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding = "ISO-8859-1" %>


  < !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd" >
< html >
  < head >
  < link rel = "stylesheet"
href = "../styles/style.css"
type = "text/css" / >
  <%
  List < TransactionLog > Allbranches = SelectOperation.getInstance().getAllTransactionLog();
List < Business > Businesslevel = SelectOperation.getInstance().getAllBusiness();
List < CustomerBranch > CustBranch = SelectOperation.getInstance().getAllCustomerBranch(); %>

< link rel = "stylesheet"
href = "//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" >
  < script src = "//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" > < /script>
  <script src="/ / code.jquery.com / ui / 1.11.4 / jquery - ui.js "></script>
  <link rel="
stylesheet " href=" / WebContent / styles / style.css "> 

<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#
fromdate " ).datepicker({
      showOn: "
button ",
      buttonImage: ".. / .. / images / calendar.png ",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      buttonText: "
Select date "
    });
  });
  
  $(function() {
    $( "#
todate " ).datepicker({
      showOn: "
button ",
      buttonImage: ".. / .. / images / calendar.png ",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      buttonText: "
Select date "
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<table align="
center " style="
background - color: #F5D0A9;
padding: 70px;
border - top: 1px;
">
<tr>
<%-- added by Maihani on 181115(Wed) --%>
<td> 
Business Id :-
</td>

<%--<td> <input type="
text " name="
BusinessId " size = "
46 "/> --%>
<td> <select   name="
Business ">
<%for(Business business : Businesslevel) {%>
<option value=" <%= business.getBusinessId() %> "><%=business.getBusinessName()%></option>
<%}

%>
</select><%-- </td>--%>
</td>
</tr>
<td>
Branch Id :
</td>
<td>
<select   name="
CustomerBranch ">
<%for(CustomerBranch custBranch : CustBranch) {%>
<option value=" <%= custBranch.getBranchId() %> "><%=custBranch.getBranchName()%></option>
<%}

%>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
From Date :
</td>
<td>
<%-- <input type="
text " name="
BrachId " size = "
46 "/> --%>
<input type="
text " id="
fromdate ">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
To Date :
</td>
<td>
<%--<input type="
text " name="
BrachId " size = "
46 "/> --%>
<input type="
text " id="
todate ">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>

</td>
 
<td align="
center "><input type="
submit " value="
Search Transaction "/></td>
 
</tr>
<tr >
<td colspan="
2 ">
<table align="
center ">
<tr bgcolor="
#333333">
<td><font color= "#FFFFFF" > User ID < /font></td >
  < td > < font color = "#FFFFFF" > Branch ID < /font></td >
  < td > < font color = "#FFFFFF" > Transaction Code < /font></td >
  < td > < font color = "#FFFFFF" > Transaction Date < /font></td >
  < td > < font color = "#FFFFFF" > Transaction Time < /font></td >
  < /tr>
<%for(TransactionLog txn : Allbranches){%>
 
<tr bgcolor="#F2F2F2">
<td><%=txn.getUserId()%></td >
  < td > <%= txn.getBranchId() %> < /td>
<td><%=txn.getTxnCode() %></td >
  < td > <%= txn.getTxnDate() %> < /td>
<td><%=txn.getTxnTime() %></td >
  < /tr>
<%} %>
</table >
  < /td>
<td></td >
  < /tr>
</table >
  < /form>
</body >
  < /html>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the submit button, you can call a JavaScript function that in turn validates the values of your 4 input types and based on the validation result, you can continue with the form submit or show error message

```
<input type="submit" onclick="validateForm()" value="Search Transaction" />

<script>
    function validateForm(){
        var ip1 = $("#firstdropdownId").val();
        var ip2 = $("#otherdropdownId").val();
        var date1 = $("#firstdateId").val();
        var date2 = $("#otherdateId").val();

        if(ip1 == null || ip1.length.trim() == 0 || ip2 == null || ip2.length.trim() == 0 || idt1 == null || dt1.length.trim() == 0 || dt2 == null || dt2.length.trim() == 0){
            $("#errorMessageDiv").show();
            return false;
        }
        else{
            $("#errorMessageDiv").hide();
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Or if you want to validate from java end, you can make an ajax call by passing the parameters as the input values, which will return the validate status of your form.

Comment: Hi Aakash Jain, thank you for the reply. But, do i need to change the name of the '#...."?

Comment: yes, you need to use the id of your input types as defined in the selector(like BrachId and alike).